# React how to add innerHtml to a dynamically created child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ive got a parent component "Dialog" that looks like the below.
It pulls in another child component "DialogBody" that requires a child react node. How can i set the innerHTML of the dynamically created "child1" div versus the parent 'getBodyHtml' (or the 'this.props.body') ?

```
class Dialog extends Component {
getBodyHtml () {
    return {
        __html: this.props.body,
    };
}
render () {

var child1 = React.createElement('div', null);

//how to set innerhtml here ??
child1.dangerouslySetInnerHTML({this.getBodyHtml()});

    return (
            {/* children is a required prop of react component */}
            <DialogBody children={child1} />
            </Dialog>
    );
```

Comment: after some more research this is probably not possible to do without changing the parent component requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the compulsory `children` prop and set `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <DialogBody dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getBodyHtml()}/></Dialog>
  )
}
```

For more info, refer to the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)